# iOS method on app update

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Hi I'm wondering if there is any method that is called when an app is updated similar to androids onUpgrade(). I'm using a SQLite database in my app and the schema has changed a lot in the new version.

If the old version is on the phone and I run the new version through Xcode. It will not work as the old tables do not correspond. The app syncs to the server so I am not worried about the users data. So I could drop all the tables on update.

Comment: Why not just check, at launch, to see if the old schema is present? (But to answer your question, no, there is no `onUpgrade()` or similar. You could save the previous-known version as a preference, but it's not a reliable or recommended practice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to indicate an upgrade. You need to determine this yourself. There are many possible approaches.

What I do in my sqlite-based app is I have a meta-data table in the database. This contains a schema version number. I check this against a hardcoded version number I put in the code. If they are different then I know the database needs to be updated. I provide sql scripts in my app that can update any prior schema version to the current version. I simply run the script that matches the version shown in the database.

This approach allows me to deal with users that haven't upgraded in a while and the schema may need to go through multiple revisions.